# Possible permalink or .htaccess error, wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

Okay. So I have a site that needs to be live around 8am EST. Everything was going fine, but when I uploaded it to the server my two pages return 404 not found errors. Absolutely everything else on the site is fine.

I have tried several things. I have reset the permalinks several times. I have deleted auto-saved files in the database. I have re-uploaded the database. I have re-uploaded the site. I have set the permission on .htaccess. I have deleted .htaccess and let it rewrite itself. Nothing has worked. Does anyone have any ideas?

The page works when it is set to default, but NOT when it is set to anything else.

**Update** This is the .htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: We would need to be able to see the code (.htaccess) to help you. Also did you do the setup in Apache for the server or are you using a shared hosting plan?

Comment: It's on the company's server...and this is my .htaccess:              # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress

Comment: Also check out this answer on Wordpress.se http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11149/htaccess-disable-wordpress-rewrite-rules-for-folder-and-its-contents

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `.htaccess` you can make these changes... although this is the default .htaccess for Wordpress it looks like it has an extra slash in front of index.php for the main redirect line. You'll also want to check to make sure that your `Virtual Host` Apache directory contains `AllowOverride All`.

In this example we're telling Apache if the request isn't for index.php then see if it's a real file and a real directory, then if it's not show them the default page. This is similar to the default behavior of Wordpress already.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=index.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^.* index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

There is also a whole Stack Exchange site devoted to Wordpress at  wordpress.stackexchange.com.

This is basically the same question:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11149/htaccess-disable-wordpress-rewrite-rules-for-folder-and-its-contents